# swift argument type () -> ()

Tags: swift, types, arguments

```
func speak(text:String, onComplete:()->()) {

    mySpeechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
    mySpeechSynthesizer.speakUtterance(mySpeechUtterance)

    onComplete()
}
```

My question is: How can I call this method?

```
speechSynthesizer.speak(actions[0], onComplete: "here")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a closure.

```
speechSynthesizer.speak(actions.first) {
    // code to be executed after speaking
}
```

This is the same as

```
speechSynthesizer.speak(actions.first, onComplete: {
    // code to be executed after speaking
})
```

but obviously, the trailing closure syntax looks much cleaner.

Explanation:

1. the first part `()` means "a function without arguments",
2. the second part `-> ()` means "without return value".

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of options. The simplest in this case is considering that `onComplete` is the last closure the next one:

```
speechSynthesizer.speak(actions[0]) {
  # onComplete code goes here
}
```

On remark to the function definition in your question. It should probably be

```
func speak(text:String, onComplete: () -> Void) {...}
```